# How to source transformer component for bug zapper circuit

Tags: circuit-design, transformer, identification, flyback, component-selection

I am looking at designing a small bug zapper circuit of the type described in [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121042/how-does-this-mosquito-zapper-circuit-work).

Here is an approximate schematic of what I am trying to build:

[image]

I have done some research into how this circuit works and also taken apart a mosquito zapper racket and tested the circuit firsthand. From this I've gain a basic understanding of how the circuit works via self oscillation and flyback.

What I'm confused about is how to correctly source the transformer component. I know I need one with 6 leads, but other than that I'm kind of in the dark. The transformer from the unit I took apart had no distinguishing markings so it wasn't much help.

Can anyone tell me what specifications I need in a transformer for this circuit to work?

Comment: Cheapest source would be to buy a dollar store mosquito zapper.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany probably true, but I'd like to source my own part if possible. I'm trying to hack this circuit for an art project, have a lot of bug zappers firing rhythmically

Comment: They're custom made for the product, if you specify the core size, ferrite material and all the winding and taping details, you can get a transformer maker to build exactly what your design requires.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Okay, but I'd assume there are some generic options that would work as well. My question here is related to what specifications a transformer needs to work in this bug zapper circuit.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima I'm not convinced that you sufficiently apprehend how the circuit works. If so, you would have written a relatively straight forward summary. I'm also not convinced that you are ready to design such a circuit. If so, you probably would have been able to provide us with a summary of the difficulties you anticipate and asked the question in a more informed and different way. Finally, because of your comment about rhythmically firing a lot of these without how you hope to achieve that nor details about what much be achieved, I'm worried this isn't the right tree to be barking up.

Comment: Killing a load of bugs for the sake of art is sadistic and cruel.

Comment: Leaving aside ethical considerations, there are many small transformers available from  Ali*xpr*s* and similar sites (look for "high voltage transformer" and pick a small one). Just don't expect a specification or circuit diagram - you will have to do some investigation yourself.

Comment: @Andyaka i'm not going to be killing any bugs lol. they're going to be set up to discharge harmlessly against a metal plate. it's just for the snapping sound and the visual spark

Comment: @jonk I've tested turning one of these on and off with a darlington transistor in the place of SW1 (took apart a cheap dollar store racket to get the test circuit). It works fine, as the current draw on the 3.3V input is below 1A. As far as apprehending how the circuit works, that's why I asked this question. I understand in a broad sense that the circuit is causing a buildup of charge in the transformer that then jumps the dielectric gap between the two nodes once stored potential (voltage) becomes sufficiently large or an object (like a bug) completes a contact between the two nodes.

Comment: @jonk The type of transformer specifications needed to achieve this behavior do not seem to be documented anywhere online, so I was hoping someone could help me understand this. The "sufficient apprehension" you say I am lacking is what I was hoping the answers to the post would help me achieve. If I already knew what kind of transformer specs I needed I wouldn't have made a post asking about it.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima I'm a self-taught hobbyist, not a professional. So I really do get where you are at. I've been in similar places. And I kind of dislike myself for speaking like some disciplinarian. I'm not. Just the opposite really. But I also can tell you are more than one question away from where you need to be. Most especially because I don't think there is a ready made solution. I think you'll need to wind this yourself. And if you need to do that a lot, it's going to require some preparation and study. Parasitics are going to eat you alive. Both construction and design will be important.

Comment: @jonk Is there a reason I can't just find a workable component through standard electronics suppliers? There are 11,443 different transformer components listed on Mouser alone, it seems like it would just be a matter of searching out one with the right specs. Boosting a small DC voltage can't be such an esoteric application as to require a custom made component, can it? That really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima I can only claim my own ignorance. I haven't attempted to study 11,443 different transformer components. So I'm ignorant. But I do know some of what's needed to design and build one and I don't think any of those standard components are designed coincidentally for your very specific need. And swatter manufacturers will custom order something, anyway. So it is my ignorance. Nothing more or less.

Comment: If you have already got one working with a darlington replacing SW1, then that sounds like the perfect hack to me. Consider your problem sufficiently solved and work out the other aspects of your art project. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

That's a custom transformer made for that specific product to work with that specific circuit. Those are not "off the shelf" components and are made in large quantities (>100,000) for pennies a piece. You can't use just any "6-lead transformer" in a circuit like this because the transformer is tuned for the circuit - it's the heart of the oscillator.

Even if you designed the circuit your self, and knew the exact spec's you need for the transformer, the NRE is going to be at minimum hundreds of dollars. So your transformers are going to be pricy in small quantities. In other words, buying whole mosquito racquets will be much cheaper than spec'ing a customer transformer.

Personally, the circuit shown is very poor, very unstable, and difficult to get functioning properly. It's deceivingly simple looking.

A better idea would be to get HV generators for your application. As a compromise, the circuitry that generates the HV ignition in xenon flash cameras should get you in the ball park.

If you really want to tackle your own design, I would start with a 3-terminal high-voltage trigger transformer. Way easier to use and most simple oscillator circuits will run it, more so than the crappy bug zapper circuit which was designed to be as cheap as possible to the point where it can't be any cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a fence charger for cattle. Plug in to 120v. You might fit it into your bug zapper. Basic unshielded wire to one connection (wire on fence line). Other connection to the ground rod. Could be used for free standing bug zapper grid when insect shorts them self out.  The chargers pulse.  You would have to hook up UV's separately

Comment: an electric cattle fence is not on continuously